# Installing RIDE(Robot Framework)

Tags: automated-tests, wxpython, robotframework, python-2.6

For automated testing on RIDE(Robot framework), I had already installed PYTHON 2.6 and wxPython 3.0 version,PATH had already been updated in Environment variables, and when I jumped to the last phase i.e Installing RIDE(version -"robotframework-ride-1.3.win32.exe") through Windows Installer, application is been installed when I try to through "Run as Administrator", it was unable to open the IDE. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: how do you define "unable"? Does your computer reboot? Fail silently? Throw an error? What error?

Comment: I'd love to answer this, but I don't know what you're asking.  Please have a look at Jon Skeet's tips on how to ask a good question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: The installation instructions say that wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Unicode support is the only officially supported version yet you have 3.0? From a command prompt, execute ride.py and you should get something you can post here https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Answer (score 2):

I installed RIDE a few days ago with no problem.

First you need to install python like you did (run the command: "*python --version*" to verify the installation).

After that, you will need to install [Robot Framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework) (run the command: "*pybot --version*" to verify the installation)

If Robot Framework was sucessfully installed then it's time to install [wxpython](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#msw) (choose the right installation, depending on the python version installed)

Finally you only need to install [RIDE](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-ride/downloads/list) and it should work

Comment: Thanks Nuno I wanted to know which version does these all installation work for?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps given below to install robotframework.

Install Python 2.7.1
RIDE runs only on the regular Python, not on Jython nor IronPython.

Download `Python 2.7.1`

Install `Python 2.7.1`.

Set the path in environment variable. (Look below for instructions )

Note: Python 2.6 is the minimum version. Robot Framework, RIDE does not yet support Python3 .

Set path on Windows 8 (Windows 7 users also can try the steps)

Open `Start` and
search `Environment Variables`

Click on `Edit the system environment variables`

Goto `Advanced` tab

Click on `Environment Variables` button

Scroll down under System variables and click on `Path`

Click on `Edit button`

Append  `;<InterpreterInstallationDir>;<InterpreterInstallationDir>\Scripts\` in variable value Save the changes.

If command prompt is already open, then re-open command prompt to effectively take changes.

---

Install `wxPython 2.8.12.1`
It is necessary to install wxPython because RIDE’s GUI is implemented by using wxPython.

Download wxPython 2.8.12.1 directly from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/python-2.7.10.msi

Run the installer and finish the setup. This will install wxPython 2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1 on your system.

---

Install `PIP 1.1`
To install PIP follow the step by step instruction provided here http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/

Install `Robotframework 2.9rc1`

Using Command Prompt
You can install RIDE by using the pip or  easy_install commands.

Run either of the following command to install Robotframework:

```
    pip install robotframework ride

                OR

    easy_install robotframework ride
```

After the installation of RIDE, run the following command:

```
`ride.py`    (this will launch RIDE )
```

Using Windows Installer
Download robotframework-RIDE 1.4:

You can download RIDE installer for windows version from

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/robotframework-ride/robotframework-ride-1.4.tar.gz

Open the installer and follow the onscreen instructions. After installation, launch RIDE by double clicking the shortcut icon.

This should resolve the issue.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the different versions for wxPython and Python in your machine. Always make sure you should install the wxPython version same as the python version i.e. Python 2.7.